# Testing build pipeline locally using Gitlab-Runner within Docker. Error: 'folder' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to learn how to use CI/CD and wanted to test the build pipeline locally, without a need to use web interface in gitlab. A little search pointed me towards `gitlab-runner exec` running within a docker. All is done within Windows machine

I created a simple .git repository with the simples build script:

```
image: alpine
  
test:
  script:
    - echo "Hello Runner"
```

and within this repo creating a docker:

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always -v ${PWD}:/opt/devops -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine
```

Executing it:

```
docker exec -it -w /opt/devops gitlab-runner gitlab-runner exec docker test
```

And all this brings me to this output:

```
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=20 revision=2a70a833 version=15.1.1
WARNING: You most probably have uncommitted changes.
WARNING: These changes will not be tested.
Running with gitlab-runner 15.1.1 (2a70a833)
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image alpine ...
Pulling docker image alpine ...
Using docker image sha256:d7d3d98c851ff3a95dbcb70ce09d186c9aaf7e25d48d55c0f99aae360aecfd53 for alpine with digest alpine@sha256:7580ece7963bfa863801466c0a488f11c86f85d9988051a9f9c68cb27f6b7872 ...
Preparing environment
Running on runner--project-0-concurrent-0 via 845f55c8a5f6...
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/project-0/.git/
Created fresh repository.
fatal: '/opt/devops' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

FATAL: exit code 1
```

I repeated the same process on the other machine with the same results, so I am sure it is my fault that it is not running properly, I just cant figure out, what exactly should be done to fix it. Could you guys please help? Thanks!

Comment: found this issue that maybe related to it: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4574

Answer (score 1):

You need init a repository inside the folder(just to create the .git folder):

```
git init && git add . && git commit -m "commit"
```